# ip dhcp excluded-address command no work

Tags: cisco, dhcp

I want to provide 1.1.1.101 to 1.1.1.126 using dhcp pool.
Here is my configuration

```
no ip dhcp use vrf connected
ip dhcp excluded-address 1.1.1.1 1.1.1.100
ip dhcp excluded-address 1.1.1.127 1.1.1.254
!
ip dhcp pool V1
network 1.1.1.0 255.255.255.0
default-router 1.1.1.1

R1#show ip dhcp pool
```

But the end of ip dhcp pool is not 1.1.1.126, it become 1.1.1.254

```
Pool V1 :
Utilization mark (high/low)    : 100 / 0
Subnet size (first/next)       : 0 / 0
Total addresses                : 254
Leased addresses               : 1
Pending event                  : none
1 subnet is currently in the pool :
Current index        IP address range                    Leased addresses
1.1.1.102            1.1.1.1          - 1.1.1.254         1
```

Is it any wrong configuration?